# HHVM Runtime Configuration

Tags: php, hiphop, hhvm

I'm performance-tuning and debugging a PHP/HHVM CLI app, and I'm finding very difficult to get a detailed list of all HHVM runtime options and their meaning.

I've been checking https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Runtime-options but it seems deeply incomplete, in particular regarding the Error Handling section (which interests me the most).

I've checked several Stack Overflow answers with no avail.

Is there a complete list/guide of all HHVM runtime options?

Answer (score 0):

Link you posted is the right documentation, but, unfortunatelly, it is not up to date. You can also look at `hphp/doc/options.compiled` in source tree, but it has the same problem. I usually study source code. Hint - search for "[RuntimeOption::](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/search?q=RuntimeOption%3A%3A)".